# Mocha test it() terminate before Promise resolved. (Timeout)

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, es6-promise

I have a function:

```
const createUser = (name, email) => {
    const namePromise = db.findOne({name}).exec();
    const emailPromise = db.findOne({email}).exec();
    return Promise.all([namePromise, emailPromise])
    .then(([foundName, foundEmail]) => {
        if (foundName || foundEmail) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error("Already exists."));
        }
        // In the real implementation, a new row is added to db and returns a Promise.
        return Promise.resolve({uuid: "uuid1"});
    })
}
```

And I have a mocha test:

```
describe('Test', function() {
    it('succeed', function() {
        return createUser("user1", "name1")
        .then(function(result) {
            // should print '{uuid: "uuid1"}'
            console.log(result);
            expect(result.uuid).to.equal("uuid1");
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            expect(err).to.equal(null);
        });
    });
})
```

`npm test` result

```
 Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/Users/Federer-HYJ/Documents/coding/NodeJS/projects/chatroom_nodejs/backend_v2/test/models_user_test.js)

{ uuid: "uuid1" }
```

The correct result `{ uuid: "uuid1" }` is printed. But timeout comes before that.

Theoretical, the returned promise from createUser will be captured in it(). Then the test will pass. But it seems it() terminates before createUser() has been resolved.

What's wrong here???

Comment: In order to make `it` wait, the test case has to return a promise. Try making your test-function `async` and await the response from `createUser`. Then do the printing, the `expect`, and exception handling.

Comment: can you print out what `err` have?

Comment: @Ente, are you suggesting to change it() to it('test', async () => { test logic})?

Comment: @MohammedNagy The err is printed in the following order: 

1 failing
Error: Timeout of 2000ms...
{ uuid: "uuid1" }

It seems ".then" in "it()" has been caught after failure is printed.

Comment: @RogerHong , yes that's what i'd suggest.